# Is the "condition" of a for loop called each time for Iterables?

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements, iterable

Lets say I have the following code:

```
for (Object obj : Node.getIterable()) {
    //Do something to object here
}
```

and Node.getIterable() returns an iterable. Does the getIterable() function get called every time or only when the for loop is started? Should I change it to:

```
Iterable<Object> iterable = new Iterable<Object>();
//populate iterable with objects
for (Object obj : iterable) {
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Easy way to find out... Just wrap the Node.getIterable in an method which also writes something to the console (or a file if you prefer). Then you'll be able to see how many times it got called. My bet - it only gets called once, but I'm not confident enough of that to give a definite answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Java Language Specification details exactly what the foreach statement does. See "14.14.2 The enhanced for statement" for more information (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2). But in short, in fact the language does guarantee that the expression you're iterating over will only be evaluated once.

Answer (score 3):

Nope it doesn't. It keeps the iterable item it receives from the `getIterable()` in memory and uses that reference. Quick way to check is to put a break point at the `for` statement and debug your way in to the JDK. You'll come to know.